# Setting of face using funcall

Tags: functions, variables, symbols, funcall

I am using `funcall` to set a typeface by calling a function `select-typeface`.  I would like to remove `select-typeface`, calling `(face (funcall level-typeface depth match)`.

Cannot simply do

```
 (let ( (face (funcall level-typeface depth match)) )
```

in function `colourise`.

I might remove `funcall` and just use

```
 (let ( (face (level-typeface depth match)) )
```

Changing from `select-typeface` to `level-typeface` has became problematic, because the face is not being applied at `loc`.

```
(defun level-typeface (depth match)
  "Typeface for colouring a nested glyph at a particular depth.

DEPTH  Depth level of nested glyph.
MATCH  Indicates whether glyph is matched by a closing brace.
LOC    Location of glyph.

Returns one of `pigment-N' (N=1..dmax), or 
`pigment-unmatched-typeface', or `pigment-mismatched-typeface'"

  (cond
   ( (<= depth 0) 'pigment-unmatched-typeface)
   ( (not match)  'pigment-mismatched-typeface)
   ( t
      (let* ( (dcur depth)
              (dmax maxdepth)
              (n (mod dcur dmax))
              (levn (number-to-string n)) )

    (when (= n 0) (setq levn "8"))
        (intern-soft (concat "pigment-" levn)) ))) )

(defcustom select-typeface #'level-typeface
   "Select typeface function for colouring."
   :tag "Select function for colourising glyphs."
   :type 'function
   :group 'rich)

(defun colourise (loc depth match)
  "Highlight a single glyph at LOC according to DEPTH.

LOC    Location of character to add text properties to.
DEPTH  Nested depth at LOC, which determines the face to use.
MATCH  For a mismatched glyph, MATCH is `nil'."

  (let ( (face (funcall select-typeface depth match)) )

    (when face
      (font-lock-prepend-text-property loc (1+ loc) 'face face) )))
```

Comment: Say what you mean by *"Changing to level-typeface the typeface is not being set properly."* Do you mean that you replaced `select-typeface` by `'level-typeface`? (If not, did you try that?) Show what you tried and say what behavior or what error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying that you tried to *"remove `select-typeface`, using `(funcall level-typeface depth match)` instead of `(funcall select-typeface depth match)`.

If so, it looks like you just forgot to quote the function name:

`(funcall 'level-typeface depth match)`

`funcall` is a function. It evaluates its arguments. If you use unquoted `level-typeface` that's taken as a variable name. What you presumably want is to pass the *symbol* `level-typeface` to `funcall`, not  the value of that symbol as a variable.

Comment: Correct.  Beginning to think of removing the `funcall` and call the function directly `(level-typeface depth match)`.

Comment: Yes, if you're just coding a symbol statically as the function argument then there's no need to use `funcall`.